# Issue when store value 0.xx to database. Value auto set to Zero

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

I have an issue when trying to update the value to the database. Don't know why all my values auto change to Zero without any error

> Laravel 5.4 MySql 10.1.25-MariaDB

Example :

```
$update_status = Students::where(['section_name'=>'Class', 'name' => 'John', 'id' => 10])->update(['value' => 0.15]);
```

update success without any errors BUT the value I got after updated is ZERO

Hope someone can help. I don't know the issue come from code or database setup

Edit: my column type using **Float**, table engine InnoDB

Currently my temporary fix is convert the value to string before update

> update(['value' => **strval**(0.15)])

Comment: what is the data type of that column in database ?

Comment: It sounds like your column has the data type `integer` instead of `float`.

Comment: tks for reply, i using Float type but issue still happen

Comment: Show us the generated SQL.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE students`

Answer (score 0):

Check data type of your column in database, you are probably using INT. If you are using float or decimal numbers in your code, data type of your column has to match that value.

Comment: tks for reply, i using Float type but issue still happen